# rake in $33.27/hr plus bennies

Tags: word-meaning

> Three Year Letterman
> Replying to President Joe Biden
> Joel I’m looking forward to higher gas prices because I have a company gas card and get points back. We need prices to go up to benefit 1%ers like me who **rake in $33.27/hr plus bennies**.

> Source: [Twitter](https://twitter.com/3YearLetterman/status/1459982865500934144)

What does "beneies" stand for? Benzedrine or any amphetamine tablet? I guess that in the context above it metaphorically refers to "benefits." I am not sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a familiar term for *benefits*.

[Lexico *benny*2](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/benny)

> noun benny, plural bennies
> (informal US)
> **A benefit attached to employment.**

[formatting added]

*Benefit*, in this sense, is this:

[American Heritage Dictionary *benefit*](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=benefit)

> 2 b. A form of compensation, such as paid vacation time, subsidized health insurance, or a pension, provided to employees in addition to wages or salary as part of an employment arrangement. Also called fringe benefit.